# Rolling out Office 2007: How to handle macros and VB scripts

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office

I am about to roll out Office 2007 to 1600 users. Most of it seems straight forward, but this client is particularly worried about macros and VB scripts not working. How do you migrate them in the first place? Does anyone have a good strategy on how to handle macros/VB scripts, which may currently be in use with Office 2003?

I am also hoping they will just work, but we may bring in a scripting expert just in case they need editing. If you know anything about lack of compatibility, I am also all ears.

Thank you.

Comment: you are just now going to 2007?  Support for 2007 ends just shy of a year?

Comment: You should also TEST the deployment before rolling out it to all 1600 users... Test the files with vb and macros...

Comment: Jim B, Not my call...just a subcontractor. Xeon, we definitely plan on testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of it will not need migration. But as Office 2007 has different default security settings in regard to macros and VB code, some setting changes (presumably via GPO) would be needed to make things "work as before". There is a [short publicly available writeup published on Directions on Microsoft](http://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/sample/DOMIS/update/2006/06jun/0606ccmto2.htm) several years ago - it should help you determine the things to consider.

Comment: I called Microsoft today, and what you said is basically true. Since the macros are actually contained in each file, there is nothing to migrate. I do have to be careful that the security settings are not elevated, and that there are no 3rd party add-ons, which may be written to only use Office 2003.